# JQuery remove last number of list items

Tags: jquery, list

I have a var containing a number and need to subtract this number from the total number of list items. Then I need to remove the end items in the list eg. Total = 20; Number of list items = 18; Final number = 2; Then remove the last 2 list items.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use the [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector.

```
$( 'li:gt(' + ( maxAllowed-1 ) + ')' ).remove();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/5GdQx/

Comment: +1 So simple.. I almost re-invented the wheel. HOwever :lt() would be more apt for the scenario.

Comment: Thanks for +1. I'm not sure whether or not `lt()` would be better as he knows the max he wants in the final result. Plus this way he doesn't have to do the subtraction operation to figure out how many he has to remove.

Comment: @JAAlude: OP wants to remove the items from last hence lt would be much better I guess.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Final code...var totalImg = $("#showreel li").size() - 1;$("#buy-links li:gt(" + totalImg + ")").remove();

Answer (score 5):

`$.slice(start, [end])`

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

**UPDATE:**

Example:

`$('li').slice( -numToRemove ).remove();`

Comment: This really isn't a complete answer, but I didn't know about the $.slice function until now, thanks!  And good referencing.

Comment: it should be:
    `$('li').slice(-$('li').length + maxAllowed - 1).remove();`